# Side drawer in a web app

Tags: website-design, forms, buttons, drawer

I am wondering what are the use cases of a side drawer in a web app and what could be alternate solutions.

To be more specific, I have a form inside the drawer that opens from the right side when the user clicks a button.

[image: Invision mock of my solution]

Comment: Might not be the best screenshot since the list of users is empty. In the case that the list had entries, you would be able to view current users on the list and add new ones at the same time. A modal does not offer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to research conducted on side drawers, though for mobile. [The results are that it could cost you half of the user engagement.](https://thenextweb.com/dd/2014/04/08/ux-designers-side-drawer-navigation-costing-half-user-engagement/)

Even based on my personal UX review, I will conclude that having a dismissible interface like a side drawer within your context of the user action may not be ideal. *Why?* Semantically, a side drawer is not used for such actions.

I would suggest one of these 2 options:

**Option 1: Modal**

[image]

**Option 2: Form within current interface**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Drawers are usually used for navigation purposes and within the context of mobile apps. They make sense in that case as they are accessible to the user at all times to quickly navigate to other parts of the app.

> Navigation drawers are recommended for:
>
> - Apps with five or more top-level destinations
> - Apps with two or more levels of navigation hierarchy
> - Quick navigation between unrelated destinations
>
> https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer/

In your example it causes some problems and generate some questions:

- the button is disassociated with the drawer, opening it at an unexpected place
- are all forms going to be in drawers for consistency?
- if the user clicks or taps outside the drawer does it act as cancel?

If deviating from a regular approach creates problems and no pros then it's best to stick to regular approach and keep the form within the screen, focusing user to the task and keeping the context with the action bar.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. I do agree with the 1st issue you raised and I will try to fix that and the answer to your 2nd and 3rd question is yes.